# Why am I having memory leaks?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, memory, memory-leaks

I'm using VLD to detect memory leaks in a game I'm writing in C++. It reported no leaks at all until very recently. I have a SettingsManager class (all static methods) which loads settings and can save them (file I/O). Here's how I would load a list of "key=value" settings into a vector:

```
std::vector<Setting*> settings;
SettingsManager::loadFromFile(settingsLocation + "display" + settingsExtension, settings);
```

This vector is correctly filled and I can further process the data. The loadFromFile() method is implemented as follows:

```
std::ifstream file;
file.open(filename);
if(file.is_open())
{
    std::string line;
    unsigned pos;
    while(file.good())
    {
        Setting* s = new Setting;
        getline(file, line);
        if(line.empty())
        {
            // do not read empty lines
            continue;
        }
        // parse to Setting
        pos = line.find('=');
        s->key = line.substr(0, pos);
        s->value = line.substr(pos + 1);
        // add to vector
        settings.push_back(s);
    }
    file.close();
    return true;
}
else
{
    return false;
}
```

So, this allocates Settings (which is a simple struct with two std::string variables). I delete them from where I call the loadFromFile method with the following method call:

```
SettingsManager::deleteSettings(settings);
```

which is implemented as follows:

```
void SettingsManager::deleteSettings(std::vector<Setting*>& settings)
{
    for(std::vector<Setting*>::iterator it = settings.begin(); it != settings.end(); ++it)
    {
            delete (*it);
    }
}
```

When I debug, after the deleteSettings call all the elements in the vector are Bad Ptr's (Visual Studio 2010 Express). If I assign NULL to *it after the delete statement they are all NULL. So I really see no reason why this is giving me memory leaks.

Anyone have an idea? Thanks!

Comment: use `std::unique_ptr` and the problem magically fixes itself, or becomes a compiler error, which helps you fix it manually.

Comment: We probably need to see the header of class `Settings` and also the code of its destructor.

Comment: I don't know the answer, it might be a false positive. But there's one easy thing you can do. Don't use pointers! If you just have `std::vector<Setting>` not `std::vector<Setting*>` then there definitely won't be any leaks. I can't see any good reason to use pointers for this.

Comment: @john I figured having a vector of pointers would be more memory-efficient, or am I wrong?

Comment: @RaptorDotCpp, less I would say, because you need space for the pointer and the object. But of course it depend on precisely what you mean by efficient. In any case it's always better to write clean code first and worry about efficiency later. This doesn't sound like the most critical part of your program, you I would just go with the simplest choice, which is not to use pointers.

Comment: @john You know, I've thought about it that way too. I don't really need pointers here (I think) indeed, but I'll refactor the code later. As you said, it isn't really critical code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `continue` statement is causing at least one leak.  The beginning of the loop allocates a new `Setting` value and continue leaves the loop body without freeing the memory.  You need to delete it to prevent a leak.

```
Setting* s = new Setting;
getline(file, line);
if(line.empty()) {
  delete s;
  continue;
}
```

Overall though you are playing with manual memory management here and it's easy to get wrong.  I would highly recommend you consider using a type like `shared_ptr<Setting>` instead of a raw `Setting*`.  It will make your code much more robust

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer! Is shared_ptr something from standard C++ or from a library such as Boost?

Comment: @RaptorDotCpp i believe `shared_ptr` originated in boost but is now a part of C++11

Comment: Ok, I will surely check that out

Answer (score 0):

move

```
Setting* s = new Setting;
```

to after the continue loop that will fix your problem.

Edit:

I'll explain in more detail.  You're creating a new setting object currently for every line even the empty lines.  However, only settings objects for non-empty lines are stored in your container, which I assume you use to free the memory later.

By placing the code creating the setting object after the statement evaluating empty lines you should fix this problem.